# Consolidate packages with Cake build

Tags: cakebuild

Can Cake build verify if the NuGet packages in a multi-project VS solution are consolidated?

I would like the build to fail if there are multiple versions of the same NuGet dependency in use.

Answer (score 0):

Is your solution using `PackageReference`? If so you could use [Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions](https://github.com/Microsoft/MSBuildSdks/tree/master/src/CentralPackageVersions) in your MSBuild solution to manage and enforce package versions.
While this is is not a solution in Cake but in MSBuild script, it should work fine together with Cake.